# Averaging a Dynamic range in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of values that looks like this. Every 30min the top row in my data is shifted down and a new latest value is inserted. I'd like to be able to take the average of all the values in the model column from 18:30 to the top most cell each day (so just the latest cell that has an 18:30 value to the top most cell)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2pNc.png]

I've been able to find the row that contains the date I need using this:

```
=MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()-1))+TIME(18,30,0),AF47:AF4595,0)
```

So now I just need to able to average from row 1 to the output of that formula.  I've tried Index(NamedRange,1:3,0) but that didn't work

Comment: if you downvote, can you please just let me know why so I can perhaps try and change whats wrong

Comment: I did not downvote you but some of the potential reasons might be that you have not shown what you have tried on your own.  You have presented the problem and some data.  In terms of presenting data some may say its too much, you only need a small sample to show the problem.  Others dislike pictures of data and would prefer data that they can copy and paste into their own worksheets.  Finally there are those on this site that do not view excel formulas as programming and therefor immediately vote to close a question even though it states on the excel description page that formula help is ok.

Comment: I added my attempts to solve! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=INDEX(AF:AF,1):INDEX(AF:AF,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()-1))+TIME(18,30,0),AF47:AF4595,0))
```

Although I would change your formula just to shorten it...your formula is more readable.  I would change your formula to:

```
MATCH(INT(TODAY())-1+TIME(18,30,0),AF:AF,0)
```

I was assuming your data was all in AF based on your formula.  Adjust AF to match the column of your needs.

Since INDEX returns a cell address, you just need to wrap the range defined by the two indexes in an AVERAGE function:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(AF:AF,1):INDEX(AF:AF,MATCH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),DAY(TODAY()-1))+TIME(18,30,0),AF47:AF4595,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty ugly and a roundabout way of doing it, but you can first identify the last row you care about using `sumproduct()` and some sneakiness. And then pump that into your `=Average()` formula using `Indirect`:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B1:B" & SUMPRODUCT((HOUR(A:A)=18)*(MINUTE(A:A)=30)*ROW(A:A))))
```

It's going to be SLOW though hitting up all of `A:A` so maybe narrow that range down like `A1:A1000` or whatever row is likely to be the max possible row to hold that `18:30` time.

Comment: IF that does bog things down, isn't the INDIRECT function going to make working with the sheet even more painful since its a VOLATILE function and will recalculate every time something unrelated on the sheet or is it workbook changes?

Comment: Oh yea. Totally. The Index(match()) with the date manipulation is definitely the way to go (looking at your answer, I've upvoted it). I've used this `sumproduct()` method to get a row returned for some complex requirements in the past, so thought I would stick it out here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using `AVERAGEIF`:

```
=IF(NOW()-TODAY()<5.5/24,AVERAGEIF(A:A,">" & (TODAY()-5.5/24),B:B),AVERAGEIF(A:A,">" & (TODAY()+18.5/24),B:B))
```

It first checks if the current time is before 18:30 then calculates the average as described (from the last 18:30 to now)

Answer (score 0):

An AVERAGEIF/AVERAGEIFS can solve your problem but I see at least three problematic areas.

1. The `18:30:00` time you want to stop at may or may not be in the same day as the day in the top of the *Prediction Area* column. This means that you cannot construct a limiting date time from the day at the top of column AF and add `TIME(18, 30, 0)`. You might need to subtract a day if the top of column AF is after midnight and before 18:30:00. A TRUE is considered 1 in a worksheet formula and FALSE is considered zero so taking the date at the top of column AF and subtracting

   ```
   'Is the time of the datetime in AF47 less than 18:30:00?
   (MOD(AF47, 1)<TIME(18, 30, 0))
   ```

   will make the deciding date today or yesterday depending on the time in AF47.
2. Your program is inserting *Prediction Area* datetimes and *Model* numbers at the top of the list. Depending on the method, this can disrupt conventional formula range addressing, even when using absolute row references. While INDIRECT can be used to 'lock' a cell address by converting from a text string, INDEX is a more efficient method.

   ```
   'cell address with 'absolute' row (will change with inserted rows)
   AF$47
   'INDIRECT method (will not change with inserted rows)
   INDIRECT("AF47")
   'better INDEX method (will not change with inserted rows)
   INDEX(AF:AF, 47)
   'range of datetimes in column AF
   INDEX(AF:AF, 47):INDEX(AF:AF, 95)
   ```
3. Time values typically resolve to pseudo-irrational numbers (aka *repeating decimals') that cannot be relied upon in Excel's 15 significant digit floating point mathematics. For this reason you should use the 00:30:00 interval to ensure true comparity by avoiding `>=` and `<=` in favor of `>` and `<` against a time value offset by a second. IOW, `18:30:00` is not equal to either `18:29:59.999` or `18:30:00.001`.

So if your datetimes (e.g. `04/25/2019 15:00`) start in AF47 and are incremented every thirty minutes then the furthest cell you need to examine is AF95 (47 + 24*2).

With *Prediction Area* in AF46 and and *Model* in AG46 this is my effort.

```
'           |<----------AG47:AG95---------->|  |<----------AF47:AF95---------->|          |<----AF47---->|                        |<----AF47---->|
=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX(AG:AG, 47):INDEX(AG:AG, 95), INDEX(AF:AF, 47):INDEX(AF:AF, 95), ">"&INT(INDEX(AF:AF, 47))+TIME(18, 29, 59)-(MOD(INDEX(AF:AF, 47), 1)<TIME(18, 30, 1)))
```

Truth be told, the AVERAGEIFS function does suffer significantly by using full column references so if there are no rogue values that could produce false positives above or below the ranges referenced, full column references could be used for the *average_range* and *criteria1_range* cell range references. Full column references would not be affected by row/data insertion.